# Can AES-128 have a key of 15-long ASCII characters?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted h264 I-frame, and I was given a key of length 15, is this even valid?

Should not it be of length 16, so the binary representation would be 128 bits?

Comment: A "pure" AES-128 has to be of exact 16 bytes length, but depending on your cryptographic framework, a lot of libraries handle too short (or too long) keys differently. PHP/OpenSSL will fill up a too short key with x00's or truncate too long keys to 16 byte length. Other frameworks will handle a "too short string" as a password input to a key derivation function. So in short, regarding your question "This is of length 15, is this even valid?": yes, depending on the framework.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Another question, given I was not told the framework, what should I do? I mean like what is the common practice for such cases?

Comment: Kindly see the answer of @Rob Napier as he described perfectly how the key was "derived" - without knowledge of the framework and/or the key construction it is like searching the needle in a hay stack. You wrote *I was given a key...* then they should mention what system/program/framework should used to decrypt the I-frame.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a thing you could type on a keyboard, that is not a proper AES key, no matter the length. AES derives its power from the fact that its key is effectively random. Anything you can type on a keyboard in not an effectively random sequence of equivalent length. There are only about 96 characters you can type easily on a Latin-style keyboard. A byte has 256 values. 96^16 is a minuscule fraction of 256^16.

To convert a "password" that a human could type into an effectively random AES key, you need a password-based key derivation function (PBKDF). The most famous and widely available is [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). There are other excellent PBKDFs including [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) and [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2). All of them require a random salt, and all are (in cryptographic terms) very slow to compute.

That said, regarding your framework, it is not possible to guess how they have converted this string into a key. You must consult the documentation or the implementation. There are an unbounded number of ways to convert strings into keys (most of them are terrible, but there are still an unbounded selection to pick from). As Michael Fehr noted they might have done something insecure like padding with zeros. They might also have used a simple hashing function like SHA-256 and either used a 256-bit key or taken the top or bottom 128 bits. Or…almost literally anything else. There is no common practice here. Each encryption system has to document how it is implemented.

(Note that even if you see "AES-128," this is also ambiguous. It can mean "AES with a 128-bit key" or it can mean "AES with a 128-bit block and a key of 128, 192 or 256 bits." While the former meaning is a bit more common, the latter occurs often, for example in Apple documentation, despite being redundant (AES always has a 128-bit block). So even questions like "how long is the key" requires digging into the documentation or the implementation. Cryptography is unfortunately incredibly unstandardized.)

Answer (score 1):

> Should not it be of length 16, so the binary representation would be 128 bits?

You are right. For AES only key length of 128, 192 or 256 bit is valid.

I commonly see two possibilities for having a key of different length:

- You was given a password, not a key. Then you need as well to ask for a way to generate a key from the password (Hash? PBKDF2? Other?)
- Many frameworks will silently accept different key length and then trim or zero-pad the value to fit the required key size. IMHO this is not a proper approach as it gives the developers feeling the key is good and in reality a different (padded or trimmed) value is used.